# Run ngrx/effect outside of Angular's zone to prevent timeout in Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, ngrx, ngrx-effects, zone.js

I just started  to write e2e tests for my app and am running into timeout problems with Protractor and ngrx/effects.

I have the following effect dispatching an action every couple of minutes:

```
@Effect() setSessionTimer$ = this.actions$
        .ofType(Auth.ActionTypes.SET_SECONDS_LEFT)
        .map(toPayload)
        .switchMap(secondsLeft => Observable.concat(
            Observable.timer((secondsLeft - 60) * 1000).map(_ => new Auth.SessionExpiringAction(60)),
            Observable.timer(60 * 1000).map(_ => new Auth.SessionExpiredAction())
        ));
```

Trying to run a Protractor test causes the test to timeout with the following error, since Angular is not stable.

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish
>   after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an
>   Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details:
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
>   While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector,
>   .toolbar-title)

According to this issue (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3349) I need to use NgZone to run an interval Observable outside of Angular. I have tried different combinations of `this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular()` but nothing worked and the tests keep on timing out.

For example this does not work:

```
@Effect() setSessionTimer$ = this.actions$
        .ofType(Auth.ActionTypes.SET_SECONDS_LEFT)
        .map(toPayload)
        .switchMap(secondsLeft => this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => Observable.concat(
            Observable.timer((secondsLeft - 60) * 1000).map(_ => new Auth.SessionExpiringAction(60)),
            Observable.timer(60 * 1000).map(_ => new Auth.SessionExpiredAction())
        )));
```

I have no idea how to run the effect outside Angular.
Has anybody successfully e2e tested their ngrx app?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The solution is to schedule the timer observable to run outside of NgZone and then re-enter the zone when something interesting occurs.

First you are going to need two utility functions that wrap any scheduler and cause the effect to enter or leave the zone:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Scheduler';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';


class LeaveZoneSchduler {
  constructor(private zone: NgZone, private scheduler: Scheduler) { }

  schedule(...args: any[]): Subscription {
    return this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => 
        this.scheduler.schedule.apply(this.scheduler, args)
    );
  }
}

class EnterZoneScheduler {
  constructor(private zone: NgZone, private scheduler: Scheduler) { }

  schedule(...args: any[]): Subscription {
    return this.zone.run(() => 
        this.scheduler.schedule.apply(this.scheduler, args)
    );
  }
}

export function leaveZone(zone: NgZone, scheduler: Scheduler): Scheduler {
  return new LeaveZoneSchduler(zone, scheduler) as any;
}

export function enterZone(zone: NgZone, scheduler: Scheduler): Scheduler {
  return new EnterZoneScheduler(zone, scheduler) as any;
}
```

Then using a scheduler (like `asap` or `async`) you can cause a stream to enter or leave the zone:

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';
import { enterZone, leaveZone } from './util';

actions$.ofType('[Light] Turn On')
    .bufferTime(300, leaveZone(this.ngZone, async))
    .filter(messages => messages.length > 0)
    .observeOn(enterZone(this.ngZone, async))
```

Note that most of the time-based operators (like `bufferTime`, `debounceTime`, `Observable.timer`, etc) already accept an alternative scheduler. You only need `observeOn` to re-enter the zone when something interesting happens.

Comment: It works! How did you find that out about schedulers and observeOn?

Comment: Runs great!Thanks!

Comment: This worked perfectly! Scheduler has been deprecated though, it's now SchedulerLike.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Indeed some APIs are deprecated, just use the code sample from the next response by @mohlendo.

Comment: In the usage example it is better to use `queue` (`import { queue } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';`) when leaving the zone - `.observeOn(enterZone(this.ngZone, queue))`. If `async` is used then change detection is run twice.

Answer (score 17):

For Angular 6 and RxJS 6 use the following code:

```js
import { SchedulerLike, Subscription } from 'rxjs'
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core'

class LeaveZoneScheduler implements SchedulerLike {
  constructor(private zone: NgZone, private scheduler: SchedulerLike) { }

  schedule(...args: any[]): Subscription {
    return this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() =>
      this.scheduler.schedule.apply(this.scheduler, args)
    )
  }

  now (): number {
    return this.scheduler.now()
  }
}

class EnterZoneScheduler implements SchedulerLike {
  constructor(private zone: NgZone, private scheduler: SchedulerLike) { }

  schedule(...args: any[]): Subscription {
    return this.zone.run(() =>
      this.scheduler.schedule.apply(this.scheduler, args)
    )
  }

  now (): number {
    return this.scheduler.now()
  }
}

export function leaveZone(zone: NgZone, scheduler: SchedulerLike): SchedulerLike {
  return new LeaveZoneScheduler(zone, scheduler)
}

export function enterZone(zone: NgZone, scheduler: SchedulerLike): SchedulerLike {
  return new EnterZoneScheduler(zone, scheduler)
}
```

The effect should look like:

```js
import { asyncScheduler, queueScheduler } from 'rxjs'
import { filter, observeOn, bufferTime } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { enterZone, leaveZone } from './util';

actions$.ofType('[Light] Turn On')
  .pipe(
    bufferTime(300, leaveZone(this.ngZone, asyncScheduler)),
    filter(messages => messages.length > 0),
    observeOn(enterZone(this.ngZone, queueScheduler)),
  )
```